# Why have PHP6 books been written even though it has not been released?

Tags: php

I see books about PHP6, but PHP6 has not been released yet. How can people can write books even before releasing? Will these books contents be valid once the actual version of PHP6 is being released?

Comment: [This should answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#PHP_7) that query - PHP6 was abandoned and will never be released. PHP7 is the next major version.

Comment: I bought this book without knowing that fact. Does it mean  that reading it is useless?

Comment: Everyone can write a book about anything he/she likes. All details of a future version of an open source projects release is well known in advance. And once you think about it you realize it does make sense to write a book in advance: otherwise the release would be there without any book available. Even if php6 will never get released the changes in there will not be dumped. There are partly already released in version 5, partly they will be introduced in version 7. So nothing you read is lost :-)

Comment: What year was that book written? I'd say that if it is not ideal, it's not because of the PHP version, but because of the age of the material. Does it cover namespaces, traits, generators, etc?

Comment: I would not read a book about PHP 6, because it's a book about a version of PHP that doesn't exist. Even if parts of it end up in other versions, there's no guarantee about whether what's in the book and what exists in reality are the same thing. The author(s) jumped the gun and are now looking stupid, that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP6 was supposed to bring unicode support and would have caused major changes both to the internals of the language and to user code. Later on they merged that development into PHP5.3 and PHP5.4

Maybe the writer wrote something about those functionalities that were merged into 5.3/5.4

BTW, PHP7 was released early December 2015